# How to separate volume level for front and rear panels and yet keep single sound device?

Tags: audio, playback, volume-mixer, front-panel

I have realtek HD Audio, and I'm pretty satisfied with its settings — my main speakers are connected to the rear panel and whenever I turn headphones in on the front panel, the former go silent and I use headphones.

However, I noticed that the volume level for both panels is constant, so whenever I change one the other changes. That is kind of annoying since my headphones are way more louder than the speakers.

So, I would like to keep the volume for rear panel output at **100%** and front panel at say **20%**. Is that achievable?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @JoelBarsotti No, I did not. I keep swinging the volume level up and down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured it out.  It seems pretty counter intuitive, but works correctly.

You have to go into the advanced options.
[image]

Then select "Make front and rear output playback two different audio streams".
[image]

And presto.  If you make the headphones your default device, then when you unplug the headphones windows falls back to the rear panel for audio.

Comment: Thanks. I know the method (I tried it before), yet I refused to go on with it since some applications (games mostly) require a restart after changing current audio output device. Without separating into two streams they do not need a restart. However, now I see that there is indeed no simple solution to that and yours are the best there could be without programming.